# The 「って」 + 「いい」 in this sentence what does it mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

This is piece of dialogue from a book, and i don't quite get what the 「って」 is doing, if it's a quote, i don't get why they would need to phrase it as a quote. I'm guessing the 「いい」 is the word for "good"

「異世界に行かない？　一つだけ好きな物を持っている **って** *いい*わよ。」

I can guess the the full sentence is something like "you are allowed to take only 1 item you like with you" since the previous was "won't you go to another world?" from context but i want to know what the 「って」 and 「いい」 are for.

Comment: There's a typo. It's いって, not いるって. In kanji, it's 行って. Does this sentence make sense to you then?

Comment: Ah, i see. I just checked it and you're completely right. I feel quite stupid now. Thank you. yeah, i understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your sentence is 持って行っていい.

していい means "be allowed to".

持っていっ is a euphonic change of 持っていき, which is 連用形(te-form) of 持っていく.